# Which is most correct - coalesce(sum(value)) OR sum(coalesce(value))?

Tags: sql

I have seen both on SO, but I wonder if there is a "best practice" or advantage to coalesce the sum before or after:

```
coalesce(sum(value),0)  OR  sum(coalesce(value),0)
```

Just curious...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They don't do the same thing. Putting the `COALESCE` inside does not do anything if you have no records. Putting it outside changes the result in that case too to `0`. Which to use depends on the result you want.

Answer (score 12):

The SQL engine will probably optimize this anyway but using

```
coalesce(sum(value),0)
```

may be a bit faster because the summing can be done without the need to process a function and at the end `coalesce` is called **one time**.

The secone version calls `coalesce` **for every record** and sets the value to `0` if there are `null` values in the summing.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, at least, if `sum()` hits any `null`s it already treats them as 0, as long as there are other non-`null` values to sum.  You still need the outer `coalesce` though for the case @hvd mentions above (all nulls).